# Creating an Interactive, Selectable Plot for Categorical Variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset with about 100 categorical variables, and for each categorical variable, there are variables `year.exited` and `frequency` associated with it. A small example is below

```
sample.df <- structure(list(issue = c("alliance", "alliance", "alliance", 
"alliance", "alliance", "animals", "animals", "animals", "dispute", 
"dispute"), year.exited = c(1953, 1954, 1957, 1959, 1967, 1983, 
1987, 1988, 1964, 1967), frequency = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(
    issue = c("alliance", "animals", "dispute"), .rows = structure(list(
        1:5, 6:8, 9:10), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

For a small dataframe like this, it is easy to plot the year on the x, frequency on the y, and have a different color for each issue.

```
ggplot(sample.df, aes(x=year.exited, y = frequency, color = issue)) + geom_point()
```

However, my actual data frame has over 100 `issue`s, so using it and the above ggplot line is unwieldy and unreadable.

How can I make an interactive plot, where the user can select any number of values in the `issue` column, and have only those show up on the plot? I'm basing this off of the similar Excel functionality.

Comment: I couldn't figure out if shiny was what I needed. I skimmed through some tutorials and they seemed really complex for what I was looking for. Is that the easiest path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shiny` can help you do lot of things and would be a general solution but without getting too complicated you can also use `plotly` to make your graphs interactive.

Using `plotly` is easy as you just need to call `ggplotly` with the `ggplot` object that you have created.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

plot <- ggplot(sample.df, 
               aes(x=year.exited, y = frequency, color = issue)) + 
               geom_point()
ggplotly(plot)
```

1. `plotly` would provide you interactivity. When you hover or click on certain point it will show you additional details about that point.

[image]

2. Moreover in the legend user can select which `issue` they want to show/hide by clicking on the legend.
3. You can also zoom in/out at particular point using `plotly`.

Answer (score 0):

I've just updated my package 'rAmCharts4' to add the possibility to have a scrollable legend:

[image]

**Installation**: `remotes::install_github("stla/rAmCharts4")`.

#### Usage

You have such data:

```
> head(dat, 12)
   issue    x        y
1  7yJyH 1901 4.880884
2  7yJyH 1901 2.371200
3  7yJyH 1901 6.831911
4  7yJyH 1901 3.224556
5  7yJyH 1901 4.244544
6  7yJyH 1902 4.603344
7  7yJyH 1902 4.763735
8  7yJyH 1902 3.885964
9  7yJyH 1902 4.151134
10 7yJyH 1902 1.183346
11 AgBzE 1902 3.083346
12 AgBzE 1903 3.240257
```

Then here is the code for the chart:

```
dat$id <- 1:nrow(dat)

amScatterChart(
  data = reshape2::dcast(dat, id + x ~ issue, value.var = "y"),
  width = "900px",
  height = "600px",
  xValue = "x",
  yValues = unique(dat$issue),
  draggable = FALSE,
  backgroundColor = "#10101d",
  pointsStyle = amCircle(radius = 4),
  tooltip = amTooltip(
    text = "x: {valueX}\ny: {valueY}"
  ),
  chartTitle = "Scrollable legend",
  xAxis = list(title = amText(text = "x",
                              fontSize = 19,
                              color = "gold"),
               labels = amAxisLabels(color = "whitesmoke",
                                     fontSize = 17)),
  yAxis = list(title = amText(text = "y",
                              fontSize = 19,
                              color = "gold"),
               labels = amAxisLabels(color = "whitesmoke",
                                     fontSize = 17),
               gridLines = amLine(color = "whitesmoke",
                                  opacity = 0.4, width = 1)),
  caption = amText(text = "[font-style:italic]rAmCharts4[/]",
                   color = "yellow"),
  legend = amLegend(position = "bottom", maxHeight = 100, scrollable = TRUE),
  theme = "dark")
```